# 13.04 headphones not working [ASUS R500VM]

Tags: 13.04, asus, headphones

After recently succeeding with dual-ubuntu-win8 installation I got problem with my headphones not working. When I plug them my sound is muted. Tried many solutions found here , but not even one seems to be working. Anyone got simmilar problem on ASUS? If You need any logs, confs just tell me and I will paste them here.